# get file or directory with gitlabr

Tags: r, gitlab, tidyverse

I am trying to get a file in a gitlab repository using gitlabr, an R package with convenience functions for Gitlab's API.

I am able to return that a file exists in a location, but when I try to get the file I pull an error, see below.

Can post a reprex if someone has an open gitlab repo they can refer me to for which to point the first few reference variables.

Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(gitlabr)

private_token <- "12...yz"
project <- "projectname"
path <- "project_subdir"
ref <- "branch_of_interest"

con <- gl_connection("https://gitlab.myurl.org", private_token = private_token)

dir <- con(gl_list_files, project = project, path = path, ref = ref) %>% arrange(name) %>% tail(1)


> con(gl_file_exists, project = project, file_path = str_c(dir$path, "/metadata.json"), ref = ref)
[1] TRUE

> con(gl_get_file, project = project, file_path = str_c(dir$path, "/metadata.json"), ref = ref)
Error in http_error_or_content(.) : Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

Comment: I come up with same problem recently. but I have another solution. And I have already submit an issue to `gitlabr` maybe u can check it out.
https://github.com/jirkalewandowski/gitlabr/issues/8 p.s. I think `httr` is a more stable solution~XD~

Comment: I looked at your issue post, I think its a nice solution for both the special "/" character issue, and the overwriting one. Unfortunately, the main developer of the package is deceased and I am not sure who owns the repo.
https://manifestoproject.wzb.eu/uploads/obituary-jirka-lewandowski.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since been able to request archive or specific files from a repository using `httr` and the gitlab API directly.

See [download directory from a branch using Gitlab API v4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60176078/9806500) for more information.