# download directory from a branch using Gitlab API v4

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to download a directory inside of a 'release' branch of a repository from Gitlab. I am using API v4.

The branch includes is of the below structure:

```
- archive
  - outputs
    - history-2020-01-01T142535 
    - history-2020-01-15T142559
    - history-2020-02-01T142540
```

I want to get the "history-2020-02-01T142540" directory.

I can get a ZIP archive of the entire branch...

```
https://<GITLAB_URL>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/repository/archive.zip?sha=<BRANCH_ID>
```

How do I get a ZIP archive of only a specific folder within that branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible now with this endpoint

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive?sha=<commit_sha>&path=<path>"
```

The `path` parameter allows you to specify the subfolder path.

Link to gitlab documentation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive

Answer (score 2):

You can't get an archive for a specific file or folder.

But you can do something similar which might help you:

- **[Get file from repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository)**
- **[List repository tree](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree)**

Comment: I see, I can get an archive of an entire branch. If I want individual files I think you are proposing to... (1) get the list of files in the repository, (2) filter the list to include only those files I want, (3) loop through list to get each file. Is that accurate?

Comment: Right! But actually It depends on your repository size. If your repository has many files, and you have to send bunch of requests, It's better to download and iterate through files on your local system.

Comment: Anticipated my next question: when to pull the whole repo and remove unneeded items _versus_ asking for a set of files one-at-a-time. Thanks!